# Specify Custom "redirect_uri" in FB.ui() to post

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using "**Facebook Javascript Sdk**" for posting msgs in User's wall.

But here in I am dealing with dynamic redirect url. So explicitly I am passing "**redirect_uri**"  as a **link with query string** in FB.ui() method. But there is no effect .
After posting to facebook the page specified as **APP callback url** is being rendered.

So kindly suggest me how to achieve the dynamic **redirect_uri** issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you debug and see if the dynamic url is properly created and whether you can paste the url in a new tab and open it without any problem?. also it will help if you can post some code.

Answer (score 0):

When using `FB.ui`, you should never pass a redirect_uri, as the response will be returned via the callback function, not via a redirect.